# C# Arraylist removing paired duplicate values

Tags: c#, arraylist

Removing copies from Arraylist based on pairing:

If you start with:

```
"Rock" "is" "WWE" "Superstar" "How" "is" "pet" "Rock" "is" "WWE" "Superstar" "How" "is" "pet"
```

Then output should be:

```
"Rock" "is" "WWE" "Superstar" "How" "is" "pet"
```

Only one copy removing other matching pair duplicate.

Comment: ArrayList has elements "Rock","is","How","are","Rock","is","How","are". Output should select only one paired copy: "Rock", "is","How","are"

Comment: Can this be an [X-Y problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) ?

Comment: "rock","is","wwe","wwe","superstar","rock","is","wwe","wwe","superstar" one pair should get selected even if it has wwe as duplicate in between. Selection should be only pairing wise. I'm trying with arraylist like : for(int i=0;i<arraylist.count;i++){for(int j=0;j<arraylist.count;j++){ if(arraylist[i].equals(arraylist[j])arraylist.remove(arr[j]); but this is not the solution as it removes "wwe" as the requirement is like pairing selection.

Answer (score 0):

use linq `Linq.Distinct().ToArray()`

Comment: is this going to select the paired copies because my arraylist should contain only distinct paired values and copies should be removed...

Comment: Try it and find out! Start a new project just to test the effects of this recommendation. Learning is fun.

Comment: I think that this is not what OP is after; a simple `Distinct()` will return `"Rock", "is", "WWE", "Superstar", "How", "pet"`. Notice that there is an `"is"` missing between `"How"` and `"pet"`.

Comment: Ya but my requirement is removing "paired" duplicates say if "Rock" "is" "how" "are" appear two times in sequence then keep only one copy

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, this will remove every second occurrence of each string (which is, I believe, what you need):

```
string[] input = new string[]
{
    "Rock", "is", "WWE", "Superstar", "Rock", "is", "WWE", "Superstar", "How", "is", "pet", "How", "is", "pet" 
};

input.GroupBy(x => x)
     .SelectMany(x => x.Skip(x.Count() / 2))
     .ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: what if there are three paired matches or more and also if arraylist has only "Rock" "Rock" .. pls provide fullproof expression for the same.

Comment: @user1502952 Is there some *very* specific reason that prevents you from turning Visual Studio on and trying this sample yourself? Or do you really expect me to try it for you? Try it out and be specific about what you would like to change.

Comment: ok Output is Rock is is WWE Superstar How pet. Requirement is that be it any  number of elements in arraylist paired one should be removed. say if two elements matching one removed , three elements matching other consecutive three element, removed ...